# Python return statement error " 'return' outside function"

Tags: python

When running the following code (in Python 2.7.1 on a mac with Mac OS X 10.7)

```
while True:
    return False
```

I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

I've carefully checked for errant tabs and/or spaces. I can confirm that the code fails with the above error when I use the recommended 4 spaces of indentation. This behavior also happens when the return is placed inside of other control statements (e.g. if, for, etc.).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What the interpreter says, you're not inside a function. Control statements aren't functions, you define a function with `def`.

Comment: You're probably looking for `break`.

Comment: I use `yield` which gives me the same error, reason is the same, shall be in a function..

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The *return* statement only makes sense inside functions:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        return False
```

Comment: Raymond, did you get so many rep points that your counter rolled back over to 0?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: your comment confuses me.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire His account has only existed for three days.

Comment: I will be naming name my first child @Raymond-Hettinger

Comment: I have been losing sleep over this

Answer (score 34):

Use `quit()` in this context. `break` expects to be inside a loop, and `return` expects to be inside a function.

Comment: This works in case you just want to stop the script, as you would do with a void return. I'd rather use sys.exit() though, because then an exit status can be specified. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programatically-stop-execution-of-python-script

Answer (score 12):

To break a loop, use `break` instead of `return`.

Or put the loop or control construct into a function, only functions can return values.

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation on the [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) statement, `return` may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition. The same is true for [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield).