# Return outside function error in Python

Tags: python, function

This is the problem: 
Given the following program in Python, suppose that the user enters the number 4 from the keyboard. What will be the value returned?

```
N = int(input("enter a positive integer:"))
counter = 1
while (N > 0):
    counter = counter * N
    N = N - 1
    return counter
```

Yet I keep getting a outside function error when I run the system 
what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python return statement error " 'return' outside function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842120/python-return-statement-error-return-outside-function)

Answer (score 7):

You can only return from inside a function and not from a loop.

It seems like your return should be outside the while loop, and your complete code should be inside a function.

```
def func():
    N = int(input("enter a positive integer:"))
    counter = 1
    while (N > 0):
        counter = counter * N
        N -= 1
    return counter  # de-indent this 4 spaces to the left.

print func()
```

And if those codes are not inside a function, then you don't need a `return` at all. Just print the value of `counter` outside the `while loop`.

Answer (score 5):

You have a `return` statement that isn't in a function.  Functions are started by the `def` keyword:

```
def function(argument):
    return "something"

print function("foo")  #prints "something"
```

`return` has no meaning outside of a function, and so python raises an error.

Answer (score 5):

You are not writing your code inside any function, you can return from functions only. Remove return statement and just print the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by the other contributers, you could print out the counter and then replace the return with a break statement.

```
N = int(input("enter a positive integer:"))
counter = 1
while (N > 0):
    counter = counter * N
    N = N - 1
    print(counter)
    break
```

Comment: try not to repeat others' answer

Comment: @Godot How is this a repetition. I acknowledge the previous answers and suggested a break statement  to be used in the while loop.

Comment: It doesn't change logic. If other answers are in functions and if you just extract them outside a function and don't change anything, no one would be consider your answer as helpful.

Comment: and also question is about returning value and you doesn't have any 'returns' in your answer

Answer (score 0):

It basically occours when you return from a loop you can only return from function

Comment: We can also return from loop if required.