# can return statement only be used inside of the definition of a function in python?

Tags: python

New to python and hope this is not trivial. I searched through google, and did not find a related answer.

This is a loosely related answer. I understand all of it, while it does not answer my question. 
[Why would you use the return statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python)

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: Also [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) states that "return may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition, not within a nested class definition."

Comment: Is there any context that led you to ask this question?

Comment: What would you expect it to do outside of a function?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Maybe we can offer you the right keyword you're looking for.

Comment: @PM2Ring Whoops, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842120/python-return-statement-error-return-outside-function would have been a better one.

Comment: @metatoaster It's still not perfect, but it's got an accepted answer by a Python core dev, so I guess it's close enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can only be used inside a function—this is defined in the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):

> `return` may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition, not within a nested class definition.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)?

> `return` may **only** occur syntactically nested in a function definition, not within a nested class definition.

[*Emphasis mine*]

Also, considering the purpose of the `return` statement, it would not even make sense if it was usable outside of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a `SyntaxError` if you try.

When in doubt, use the interactive interpreter by invoking `python` without any arguments:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep  1 2016, 20:27:38) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160822] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> return 4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>>>
```

It will help a lot for debugging and trying things out.

Comment: Also, typing `help('return')` at the interactive interpreter prompt is quite informative.