# Using sys.exit or SystemExit; when to use which?

Tags: python

Some programmers use `sys.exit`, others use `SystemExit`.

1. What is the difference?
2. When do I need to use `SystemExit` or `sys.exit` inside a function?

Example:

```
ref = osgeo.ogr.Open(reference)
if ref is None:
    raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % reference)
```

or:

```
ref = osgeo.ogr.Open(reference)
if ref is None:
    print('Unable to open %s' % reference)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.exit "Most systems require it to be in the range 0-127, and produce undefined results otherwise." So `sys.exit(-1)` is maybe not the best idea.

Comment: sys.exit() accepts the same optional argument as SystemExit. So, it's more correct to compare SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % reference) with sys.exit('Unable to open %s' % reference). In this case (the argument is not integer nor None), they both print it to stderr and exit the process with code 1. Useful to exit process with an error message by one-liner, if you don't mind the exact exit code.

Comment: The concern about `exit(-1)` is not theoretical: POSIX systems use exit code -1 to indicate that the process was killed by SIGHUP, and will probably mangle your -1 to something else.

Comment: Considering your program exits because of being unable to open something... Maybe you should be throwing an `IOError` or another applicable error instead of `SystemExit`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No practical difference, but there's another difference in your example code - `print` goes to standard out, but the exception text goes to standard error (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Hi RichieHindle!..I [**read here**](http://blog.engledew.com/post/344116632/killing-python-exiting-without-using-systemexit) There is difference between two in multi-threaded python code. What I understood: The Call of SystemExit in multi-thread will destroy thread only? Am I correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: They are still the same.  Either will cause the current thread to exit. (The "change" talked about in that blog post is the difference between the main thread and a background thread, not between `exit` and `SystemExit`.)

Answer (score 43):

`sys.exit(s)` is just shorthand for `raise SystemExit(s)`, as described in the former's docstring; try `help(sys.exit)`. So, instead of either one of your example programs, you can do

```
sys.exit('Unable to open %s' % reference)
```

Answer (score 34):

There are 3 exit functions, in addition to raising `SystemExit`.

The underlying one is `os._exit`, which requires 1 int argument, and exits immediately with no cleanup.  It's unlikely you'll ever want to touch this one, but it is there.

`sys.exit` is defined in sysmodule.c and just runs `PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_SystemExit, exit_code);`, which is effectively the same as directly raising `SystemExit`.  In fine detail, raising `SystemExit` is probably faster, since `sys.exit` requires an `LOAD_ATTR` and `CALL_FUNCTION` vs `RAISE_VARARGS` opcalls. Also, `raise SystemExit` produces slightly smaller bytecode (4bytes less), (1 byte extra if you use  `from sys import exit` since `sys.exit` is expected to return None, so includes an extra `POP_TOP`).

The last exit function is defined in `site.py`, and aliased to `exit` or `quit` in the REPL.  It's actually an instance of the `Quitter` class (so it can have a custom `__repr__`, so is probably the slowest running.  Also, it closes `sys.stdin` prior to raising `SystemExit`, so it's recommended for use only in the REPL.

As for how `SystemExit` is handled, it eventually causes the VM to call os._exit, but before that, it does some cleanup.  It also runs `atexit._run_exitfuncs()` which runs any callbacks registered via the `atexit` module.  Calling `os._exit` directly bypasses the `atexit` step.

Comment: Another advantage of raising the SystemExit manually is that not all static analyzers understand that the execution will be interrupted after calling sys.exit. This is important, for example, so that the analyzer can detect execution paths where a referenced variable may not be defined.

Answer (score 16):

My personal preference is that at the very least `SystemExit` is raised (or even better - a more meaningful and well documented custom exception) and then caught as close to the "main" function as possible, which can then have a last chance to deem it a valid exit or not. Libraries/deeply embedded functions that have `sys.exit` is just plain nasty from a design point of view. (Generally, exiting should be "as high up" as possible)

Comment: Note that you can catch `SystemExit` exceptions in python, which would allow proper clean up of anything needed.  Of course, if you do that, make sure any nested exits use the `raise SystemExit(code)` rather than `sys.exit`, since it would be rather non-obvious if `try:... except SystemExit` caught `sys.exit` calls (anyone not aware of what exactly `sys.exit` does will probably be confused).

Answer (score 7):

According to documentation `sys.exit(s)` effectively does `raise SystemExit(s)`, so it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

While the difference has been answered by many answers, Cameron Simpson  makes an interesting point in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2016-April/857869.html:

TL;DR: It's better to just raise a "normal" exception, and use `SystemExit` or `sys.exit` only at the top levels of a script.

> > I m on python 2.7 and Linux ,  I have a simple code  need suggestion if  I
> > I could replace sys.exit(1) with raise  SystemExit .
> >
> > ==Actual code==
> >
> > ```
> > def main():    
> >     try:
> >        create_logdir()
> >        create_dataset()
> >        unittest.main()    
> >      except Exception as e:
> >        logging.exception(e)
> >        sys.exit(EXIT_STATUS_ERROR)
> >
> > if __name__ == '__main__':    main()
> > ```
> >
> > ==Changed Code==
> >
> > ```
> > def main():    
> >     try:
> >        create_logdir()
> >        create_dataset()
> >        unittest.main()    
> >     except Exception as e:
> >        logging.exception(e)
> >        raise SystemExit
> >
> > if __name__ == '__main__':    
> >     main()
> > ```
>
> I am against both of these personally. My preferred pattern is like
> this:
>
> ```
>   def main(argv):
>     try:
>       ...
>     except Exception as e:
>       logging.exception(e)
>       return 1
>
>   if __name__ == '__main__':
>     sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
> ```
>
> Notice that main() is back to being a normal function with normal
> returns.
>
> Also, most of us would avoid the "except Exception" and just let a top
> level  except bubble out: that way you get a stack backtrace for
> debugging. I agree it  prevents logging the exception and makes for
> uglier console output, but I think  it is a win. And if you *do* want
> to log the exception there is always this:
>
> try:
> ...   except Exception as e:
> logging.exception(e)
> raise
>
> to recite the exception into the log and still let it bubble out
> normally.
>
> The problem with the "except Exception" pattern is that it catches and
> *hides*
> *every* exception, not merely the narrow set of specific exceptions that you  understand.
>
> Finally, it is frowned upon to raise a bare Exception class. In
> python 3 I  believe it is actually forbidden, so it is nonportable
> anyway. But even In  Python to it is best to supply an Exception
> instance, not the class:
>
> raise SystemExit(1)
>
> > 2. All the functions in try block have exception bubbled out using raise
> >
> > Example for create_logdir() here is the function definition
> >
> > def create_logdir():
> >
> > try:
> > os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)
> > except OSError as e:
> > sys.stderr.write("Failed to create log directory...Exiting !!!")
> > raise
> > print "log file: " + corrupt_log
> > return True
> >
> > def main():
> > try:
> > create_logdir()
> > except Exception as e:
> > logging.exception(e)
> > raise SystemExit
> >
> > (a) In case if create_logdir() fails we will get the below error ,is
> > this fine or do I need to improve this code.
> >
> > Failed to create log directory...Exiting !!!ERROR:root:[Errno 17] File
> > exists: '/var/log/dummy'
> >
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "corrupt_test.py", line 245, in main
> > create_logdir()
> > File "corrupt_test.py", line 53, in create_logdir
> > os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)
> > File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
> > OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/log/dummy'
>
> I prefer the bubble out approach, perhap with a log or warning
> messages as you  have done, eg:
>
> logging.exception("create_logdir failed: makedirs(%r): %s" %
> (LOG_DIR, e))   raise
>
> (Also not that that log message records more context: context is very
> useful  when debugging problems.)
>
> For very small scripts sys.stderr.write is ok, but in general any of
> your  functions that turned out to be generally useful might migrate
> into a library  in order to be reused; consider that stderr is not
> always the place for  messages; instead reading for the logging module
> with error() or wanr() or  exception() as appropriate. There is more
> scope for configuring where the  output goes that way without wiring
> it into your inner functions.
>
> > 3. Can I have just raise , instead of SystemExit or sys.exit(1) . This
> >    looks wrong to me
> >
> > def main():
> >
> > try:
> > create_logdir()
> > except Exception as e
> > logging.exception(e)
> > raise
>
> This is what I would do, myself.
>
> Think: has the exception been "handled", meaning has the situation
> been dealt  with because it was expected? If not, let the exception
> bubble out so that the  user knows that something *not* understood by
> the program has occurred.
>
> Finally, it is generally bad to SystemExit or sys.exit() from inside
> anything  other than the outermost main() function. And I resist it
> even there; the main  function, if written well, may often be called
> from somewhere else usefully,  and that makes it effectively a library
> function (it has been reused). Such a  function should not
> unilaterally abort the program. How rude! Instead, let the  exception
> bubble out: perhaps the *caller* of main() expects it and can handle
> it. By aborting and not "raise"ing, you have deprived the caller of
> the chance  to do something appropriate, even though you yourself
> (i.e. "main") do not know  enough context to handle the exception.
>
> So I am for "raise" myself. And then only because you want to log the
> error. If  you didn't want to log the exception you could avoid the
> try/except *entirely*  and have simpler code: let the caller worry
> about unhandled exceptions!

Answer (score 4):

`SystemExit` is an exception, which basically means that your progam had a behavior such that you want to stop it and raise an error. `sys.exit` is the function that you can call to exit from your program, possibily giving a return code to the system.

EDIT: they are indeed the same thing, so the only difference is in the logic behind in your program. An exception is some kind of "unwanted" behaviour, whether a call to a function is, from a programmer point of view, more of a "standard" action.

Comment: There is a difference between `Exception` and `Error`. An `Exception` is something unusual (`SIGINT`, a disconnected network connection, a `StopIteration Exception`). They're just a fancy way to do `escape continuations`. An `Error` is program misbehavior, (i.e. running out of memory). Python implements both `Exception`s and `Error`s as subclasses of `Exception`, but `Error`s contain `Error` in the name. `SystemExit` is an `Exception`, it only happens once. If you're exiting from nested code, raising `SystemExit` might be more obvious that it's intentional to exit from the middle of something.