# python 2.7: how to catch keyboard interrupt in program with more than 25 threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, keyboardinterrupt

I want to stop my program when the user presses ctrl-C.
The following answer suggests catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

[python: how to terminate a thread when main program ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564137/python-how-to-terminate-a-thread-when-main-program-ends)

Sometimes it works. But in the following example, it stops working after I increase the number of threads from 25 to 30.

```
import threading, sys, signal, os

stderr_lock = threading.Lock()

def Log(module, msg):
    with stderr_lock:
        sys.stderr.write("%s: %s\n" % (module, msg))

class My_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        Log("Init", "Initing.")
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                Log("Run", "Running.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            os._exit(0)

for i in range(30):
    My_Thread()

# trap ctrl-C in main thread
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os._exit(0)
```

This has a very suspiciously similar feel to the following question:

[Thread-Safe Signal API in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127695/thread-safe-signal-api-in-python-2-7)

In that case, I was unable to catch signals after increasing the number of threads beyond 87.

Comment: This works fine for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: the `KeyboardInterrupt` in the threads is not needed

Comment: @JohanL Ubuntu14. Out of curiosity, does it still work if you increase the range(30) to range(1000)?

Comment: At 1000 threads I had the same problem as you. See my answer to why and what you could do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two different issues with your code that gives this behavior. The first is that your threads should be made into `daemon` threads, so that they automatically stops when the main thread exits, the second is that your `try` block does not encapsulate the thread creation and start-up.

When you create a number of threads, the thread creation won't be finished for quite a while (since it is continuously interrupted by the created threads and the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) prevents them to run in parallel). Therefore, you send your `KeyboardInterrupt` before being set up to be handled. However, the `KeyboardInterrupt` will still kill the main thread (with a Traceback), but not the child threads.

Thus, your code works if you modify it as:

```
import threading, sys, signal, os

stderr_lock = threading.Lock()

def Log(module, msg):
    with stderr_lock:
        sys.stderr.write("%s: %s\n" % (module, msg))

class My_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, value):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
        Log("Init", "Initing %d." % self.value)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            Log("Run", "Running %d." % self.value)

# trap ctrl-C in main thread
try:
    for i in range(1000):
        My_Thread(i)

    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os._exit(0)
```

Note, that making the threads into daemons is not strictly necessary in the current example, but I would consider that to be good practice for threads that are supposed to end when the main program ends.

Comment: "When you create a number of threads, the thread creation won't be finished for quite a while (since it is continuously interrupted by the created threads and the GIL prevents them to run in parallel)."   Bingo! I never would have thought of that. Wow, in all my experience in other languages, I have never run into  one with such a bad scheduler (even on single-processor systems). Great answer. Yes, now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Or, if I had just been patient enough to let all the threads get created, my original example would have worked.... but, as I said, I never would have thought of that.

Comment: The `daemon=True` is even better. Somehow I thought that wasn't supported in pre-3.0 Python. I was wrong! Thank you for pointing this out. Actually I wasn't the first one to be confused about pre-3.0 daemon threads: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/18. So apparently Python 3.0 added `daemon` as an argument to `Thread` and then people started writing code that wasn't doing it the backward-compatible way.

Comment: The `daemon=True` has been available since Python 2.6 and before that you could use `setDaemon` instead, so I think the page you are linking to, had another type of issue, but I don't know.

Comment: As far as the GIL is concerned, it is an annoying implementation detail, but it is not only Python that has it. E.g. Ruby has a similar architecture. Threads works for code that releases the GIL (typically `numpy`) and to simplify code that is mostly waiting (typically sockets). For processor bound code that needs to be run faster, consider to use `multiprocessing` instead. As long as the processes don't communicate or share state, that is rather straight-forward. If you need to share data, it is still possible but requires a bit more of work, typically using queues.

Comment: This just in: `daemon=True` is BAD. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596918/python-exception-in-thread-thread-1-most-likely-raised-during-interpreter-shutd. BAD BAD daemon -- can't debug anything. Went back to `signal.pause()` and I can debug things again. Why couldn't they just not frickin break ctrl-C in the first place?????

Comment: Wel, yes, if the threads need to be exited properly or in order, or needs to be synchronized when the program ends, then you want to close them in  a proper way, and not make them daemons. In your example you did not have any of that, but I guess it was a down-scaled example? How do you use the signals? It might be better to just set a condition in main, that the threads check every once in  a while, to see if they should exit.

Comment: I have found that if you put every thread `run()` AND `start()` in a `try..except` and start your very first imported module with `signal.signal()` and your last module ends with `signal.pause()`, then ctrl-C works reliably. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/35430500/1656850, namely:

> There are 3 exit functions, in addition to raising SystemExit.
>
> The underlying one is os._exit, which requires 1 int argument, and
>   exits immediately with no cleanup. It's unlikely you'll ever want to
>   touch this one, but it is there.
>
> sys.exit is defined in sysmodule.c and just runs
>   PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_SystemExit, exit_code);, which is effectively
>   the same as directly raising SystemExit. In fine detail, raising
>   SystemExit is probably faster, since sys.exit requires an LOAD_ATTR
>   and CALL_FUNCTION vs RAISE_VARARGS opcalls. Also, raise SystemExit
>   produces slightly smaller bytecode (4bytes less), (1 byte extra if you
>   use  from sys import exit since sys.exit is expected to return None,
>   so includes an extra POP_TOP).
>
> The last exit function is defined in site.py, and aliased to exit or
>   quit in the REPL. It's actually an instance of the Quitter class (so
>   it can have a custom **repr**, so is probably the slowest running.
>   Also, it closes sys.stdin prior to raising SystemExit, so it's
>   recommended for use only in the REPL.
>
> As for how SystemExit is handled, it eventually causes the VM to call
>   os._exit, but before that, it does some cleanup. It also runs
>   atexit._run_exitfuncs() which runs any callbacks registered via the
>   atexit module. Calling os._exit directly bypasses the atexit step.

so, `raise SystemExit` may be the preferable way to exit when the exception is caught.

Comment: I tried it with `raise SystemExit` instead of `os._exit(0)`. That made it much worse. With `raise SystemExit` then the program only works with 1 thread (the main thread only). At least with `os._exit(0)` I can get 25 threads.

Comment: Can you add an edit to your question showing what you did when you replaced `os._exit(0)` with `raise SystemExit`? It seems inconceivable that a 1-to-1 exchange of them would change the number of allowable threads, but if you say it does - then it'd be interesting to test your code in my environment to verify this strange phenomenon.

Comment: Why is it strange for `raise SystemExit` to behave any differently from `raise KeyboardInterrupt`? Given that the latter is broken (otherwise this whole question wouldn't exist) I am not surprised about the former being broken too.