# how to stop ironpython script from C# perspective

Tags: c#, ironpython

I use IronPython script from C# like this:

```
scriptEngine = Pythn.CreateEngine();
var scriptSource = scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pathToScriptFile, Encoding.Default, SourceCodeKind.File);
scriptSource.Execute(_mainScope);
```

Script that is being started lasts a while and I would like to know if it is possible to stop it somehow from C# perspective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657514/terminating-an-ironpython-script)?

Answer (score 1):

Much like actual threads, there is no safe way to terminate running code from an external perspective, unless the running code provides a cancellation mechanism (e.g. like `CancellationToken` in .NET) or if it is running in an external process, in which case you can safely kill it off.

You could also spawn a new thread, run the code on it and kill the thread, but killing threads is very dangerous, so I would strongly advise against doing so.