# Why does an async Task.Run terminate a Thread and a Task Run does not?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am starting a Thread where an `await Task.Run` can be invoked.

After starting a Thread with the `ThreadStart.Start` method, why does the `await Task.Run` terminate the Thread and `Task.Run` does not?

Here is some code as an example:

```
public async Task Task1()
{
    if (awaitRunTask)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Test();
        }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Test();
        }
        );
    }
}
```

In the above example, if a Thread invokes the Task1 method, and `awaitRunTask = true`, the Thread terminates. If `awaitRunTask = false`, the Thread does not terminate.

When I say terminate, the Thread does not complete correctly and the method where the `ThreadStart.Start` is invoked returns. This happens at the `await Test()` code.

Why is this and if I want to await a `Task.Run` on a Thread, is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

Here is some code to show a more detailed example:

```
public class ThreadExample
{
    public bool awaitRunTask;
    public string value;
    private async Task StartThreadAsync()
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("RunTasksAsync");
        ThreadStart threadStart;
        threadStart = async () =>
        {
            await InvokeAsync(method, this, null);
        };
        var thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
    public async Task RunTasksAsync()
    {
        await Task1Async();
        Task2();
    }
    private async Task Task1Async()
    {
        if (awaitRunTask)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await TestAsync();
            }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await TestAsync();
            }
            );
        }
    }
    private void Task2()
    {
        value = "valid";
    }
    private async Task TestAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    private async Task InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, object instance, object[] parameters)
    {
        dynamic awaitable = method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
        await awaitable;
    }
    public async Task ValueIsCorrectAsync()
    {
        value = "not valid";
        awaitRunTask = false;
        await StartThreadAsync();
        var isCorrect = (value == "valid");
    }
    public async Task ValueIsNotCorrectAsync()
    {
        value = "not valid";
        awaitRunTask = true;
        await StartThreadAsync();
        var isCorrect = (value == "valid");
    }
}
```

The `ValueIsCorrectAsync` method works correctly as the `Task2` method sets the `value` field.

The `ValueIsNotCorrectAsync` method does not work correctly as the `await Task.Run` in the `Task1Async` method interferes with the Thread. The `StartThreadAsync` method returns before the `Task2` method sets the `value` field.

The only difference between the two methods, is the value of `awaitRunTask`.

How should I change my code such that the `value` field is set correctly when `awaitRunTask = true`?

**EDIT3**

If the `await Task.Delay(1000);` is commented out in the `TestAsync` method, the code works for both `awaitRunTask = true` and `awaitRunTask = false;`

Can someone please explain to me why? I need to know why because the `TestAsync` method needs to be able to run asynchronous code.

Comment: It would be super useful to know how to run the sample code.

Comment: The `StartThreadAsync` method is probably giving you a compilation warning about an `async` method that lacks an `await` keyword, correct?

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method)

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias That is correct. Even though I have async code for the ThreadStart.

Comment: Can the code be adapted such that the compilation warning does not happen, and thus resolve the problem?

Comment: Simon I mentioned the compilation warning because it should give you a clue that you are doing something wrong. To be honest there are multiple things wrong in the code, there are too many questions asked inside the same question, the questions are not presented in an easily comprehensible manner, which makes it overall a not good question IMHO. I wish I had some idea about how the question could be improved, but I don't.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias When you see the StartThreadAsync method, there is async code in it, I am not sure why the compilation warning is shown. Maybe the compiler cannot see the async code in the threadStart variable.

Comment: The code inside the `threadStart` lambda is not part of the execution flow of the `StartThreadAsync` method. Adding an `await` inside the general area of a method (from a spatial perspective) is not enough to make it a proper asynchronous method. The `await` must also be part of the method's execution flow.

Comment: Are you able to explain to me why the await Task.Delay(1000) stops the flow of execution when awaitRunTask = true?

Comment: @Simon - The answers currently explain why `await Task.Delay(1000)` stops the flow of execution. Do you understand that `async` state machine let's the calling thread return and the execution then continues after the `Task.Delay` on a thread from the thread pool?

Comment: @Simon - You really should answer my question as to who you need to do this? What's the underlying need?

Comment: @Enigmativity Can any changes be made in the `StartThreadAsync` method such that the `await Task.Delay(1000)` does not return to the calling thread? Or can the `Task1Async` or `TestAsync` methods be written differently for this to not happen?

Comment: @Simon - Can you please answer my question? Then I might be able to give you alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this?

As I explain on my blog, [`await` here is actually returning to its caller](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). So the `Task1` method returns an incomplete task to its caller, presumably the thread's main method, which presumably is `async void`. When the thread's main method returns (due to it's `await`), the thread exits.

The core of the problem is that the `Thread` type doesn't understand or work naturally with asynchronous code. `Thread` is really a very low-level building block at this point and is best avoided in modern code. There are very few scenarios where it can't be replaced with `Task.Run`.

> if I want to await a Task.Run on a Thread, is there a way to do this?

The easiest solution is to get rid of the legacy thread completely; replace it with `Task.Run`.

Otherwise, you need the thread to block. If the continuations can run on thread pool threads, then you can just block directly (e.g., `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`). If the continuations need to run on that thread, then use `AsyncContext` from my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit where I have added a more detailed example? The Join method joins the Thread, yet the await Task.Run still does not return the correct result.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave? As described there, `await` will continue synchronously if the task is already completed. So all the thread code is synchronous when `awaitRunTask` is `false`.

Comment: I have read the link you gave. In the code I have posted, the problem appears to be at the code await Task.Delay(1000). Can you explain what I should do such that the flow of execution does not stop when getting to the await Task.Delay(1000)?

Comment: @Simon: The best solution is to replace the `Thread` with `Task.Run`. Is there some reason you can't do that?

Comment: The reason that I am using the Thread is because it can be Aborted rather than having to code any additional CancellationToken code.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but `Abort` is one of the most serious *problems* with `Thread`! It is dangerous and will eventually lead to application instability. Please use the properly-designed modern cancellation system instead.

Comment: `Can someone please explain to me why?` As [described on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), it's because it runs synchronously. All your "working" examples are ones that run synchronously and are not asynchronous at all.

Comment: @Simon be aware that the `Thread.Abort` [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort) on .NET Core and later, and [never will](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11369#issuecomment-692155140).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal version of your sample code:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var te = new ThreadExample();
    await te.StartThreadAsync(false);
    await te.StartThreadAsync(true);
}

public class ThreadExample
{
    public string value;
    public async Task StartThreadAsync(bool awaitRunTask)
    {
        value = "not valid";
        var thread = new Thread(() => Task1Async(awaitRunTask));
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        var isCorrect = (value == "valid");
        Console.WriteLine(isCorrect);
    }

    private async Task Task1Async(bool awaitRunTask)
    {
        if (awaitRunTask)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
        }
        value = "valid";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
True
False
```

The thread that enters `Task1Async` executes the line `value = "valid"` when `awaitRunTask == false`, but when it's `true` it hits the `await Task.Run` and, because of the `async` state machine, the thread returns to the caller at this point and executes the `thread.Join()`.

Effectively you've created an extreme race condition.

Comment: Will the async state machine always do this, such that there is no work around?

Comment: @Simon - What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am wanting to be able run a Task asynchronously from a Thread without the Thread returning to the caller.

Comment: The Task could run anything, including an asynchronous method via reflection. The Task may or may not be awaited, hence having the await in a Boolean.

Comment: Also, the Thread I added is joined such that the code can be adapted to have a return value from the ThreadStart InvokeAsync method at a later date.

Comment: @Simon - That's a description of the solution you've presented here. What is the underlying business need for this? What problem is this solution trying to solve?

Comment: @Simon - I have tested the code (now twice) and it produces the output I included in my answer. What's exactly not working when you run my code?

Comment: I am after isCorrect == true for both StartThreadAsync(true) and StartThreadAsync(false).

Comment: @Simon - Then don't use a thread. But if you explain what your actual problem is, then maybe there's a solution.

Comment: I seem to have got the await Task Run sorted. Can you have a look at my Edit3?