# Why my input commands doesn't execute on the console?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I recently started learning Threading and I'm not quite familiar with how the things work. I decided to make a simple project of a manual gearbox, where you can shift gears and depending on which gear you are will determine how fast the kilometers will build up.
My program runs properly, till the moment when I press the "UpArrow" and nothing happens, the thread stays only on first gear. I know I'm missing something, but cant find it. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ManualGearbox
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKey command = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            int kms = 0;
            var FGthread = new Thread(() => FirstGear(kms));
            var SGthread = new Thread(() => SecondGear(kms));
            var TGthread = new Thread(() => ThirdGear(kms));
            var FourthThread = new Thread(() => FourthGear(kms));
            var FifthThread = new Thread(() => FifthGear(kms));
            
            while (command != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                if (command == ConsoleKey.S)
                {
                    FGthread.Start();
                }
                if (command == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    GearUp(FGthread, SGthread, TGthread, FourthThread, FifthThread);
                }
                command = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            }
        }

        static int FirstGear(int kilometers)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (kilometers < 20)
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + " kilometers");
                }
                else
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + " kilometers");
                }
            }
        }

        static int SecondGear(int kilometers)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (kilometers < 40)
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
                else
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
            }
        }

        static int ThirdGear(int kilometers)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (kilometers < 60)
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
                else
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
            }
        }

        static int FourthGear(int kilometers)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (kilometers < 80)
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
                else
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
            }
        }

        static int FifthGear(int kilometers)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (kilometers >= 80)
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
                else
                {
                    kilometers++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine(kilometers + "kilometers");
                }
            }
        }

        static void GearUp(Thread first, Thread second, Thread third,
            Thread fourth, Thread fifth)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread == first)
            {
                first.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Switching to second");
                second.Start();
            }
            else if (Thread.CurrentThread == second)
            {
                second.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Switching to third");
                third.Start();
            }
            else if (Thread.CurrentThread == third)
            {
                third.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Switching to fourth");
                fourth.Start();
            }
            else if (Thread.CurrentThread == fourth)
            {
                fourth.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Switching to fifth");
                fifth.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you running this code on .NET Framework or on .NET Core / .NET 7?

Comment: .Net Framework.

Comment: As expected, because the `Thread.Abort` [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort) on the latest .NET platforms.

Comment: Does that mean, that i have to switch to core?

Comment: If you switch to Core, your code will start throwing `PlatformNotSupportedException`s. Aborting threads is no longer supported on .NET. Whatever problem you are solving with the `Abort`, you'll have to find another way to solve it, otherwise you'll get stuck on .NET Framework forever.

Comment: Alright ill have it in mind, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.CurrentThread` is always the current thread. Your `GearUp` method is never invoked from any place other than from your `main()`, therefore `Thread.CurrentThread` will always be the main thread, it will never be any of your other threads.

To fix this you will need to somehow move the checking for the console key and the switching of gears within each one of your gear threads.

Do yourself a favor and quit having a separate method for each gear. They should all be implemented using just one method, which knows which gear it is via a parameter. (Or a separate class, which knows which gear it is via a constructor parameter.)