# Abort synchronous method

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to abort a synchronous method that executes for a long time?

I have the method Test that calls the `LongRunningMethod` method that consumes a lot of memory and CPU, in case it lasts longer than 30 seconds, I want to abort it. However, after an exception is thrown, the CPU and memory are still increasing, although the task is completed.

Code:

```
static async Task<string> Test (string input)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = LongRunningMethod(input, tokenSource.Token)
        .WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    try
    {
        var result = await task;
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {  
      // if the timeout is thrown, the LongRunningMethod still executes in background
      // and increase memory and CPU
    }
}

static Task<string> LongRunningMethod(string input, CancellationToken token)
{
    var task= Task.Run(() =>
    {
        SynchronousMethodThatConsumesMemoryAndCpu(input);
        return "end";
    },
    token);

    return task;
}
```

Comment: There is no answer to this question without knowing what is happening inside SynchronousMethodThatConsumesMemoryAndCpu.

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET Core and later or .NET Framework? For .NET Core see this: [.NET Core equivalent to Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort)

Comment: I do not have access to that method, it does some conversion, however, I don't want to optimize it or write it differently, I am asking if it is possible to abort the execution of that method if I cannot pass CancellationToken. I am targeting .NET 6.0

Comment: There are numerous question regarding this. But the only real alternatives are to change your `SynchronousMethodThatConsumesMemoryAndCpu` to check the cancellation token (or something equivalent), or to move the method to a separate process.

Comment: See [Whats wrong with Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567) for details.

Comment: Deleting a question when people are trying to answer is very rude. Instead of guessing or insisting on things nobody else can reproduce, create a new web api project and try `curl -X 'GET'   'https://localhost:7011/WeatherForecast'`. You get `test`. Then add `-H 'accept: application/json'`. You get `"test"`. You aren't using the POSTMAN settings you think you are

Comment: If you hadn't deleted the question I could have posted how to force JSON when no content type is specified

Comment: Rude is saying that I am lying or telling something that I am not doing when actually I am

Comment: I already told you that I am using same request, only difference is the route. If you cannot accept that, please dont try to answer

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to optimize it or write it differently, I am asking if it is possible to abort the execution of that method if I cannot pass CancellationToken.

No, there isn't. There is no official helper method or other mechanism for cancelling/aborting a method which doesn't provide a mechanism to cancel/abort (e.g. accepting a token).

In addition, in a comment from March 2022 to [Proposal for non-cooperative abortion of code execution #66480](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/66480) the Microsoft's .NET performance guru [Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/author/toub/) who has written many times about tasks and threads says:

> We've deleted a whole bunch of code in .NET Core that was there to help try to improve reliability in the face of thread aborts (...)
>
> New code has also been written assuming no thread aborts. (...)

This means that tricks with `Thread.Interrupt` are now even more dangerous.

It looks that you you would have to:

1. Run the method in a separate process; or
2. Let the method run to completion and just ignore its results if the 30 seconds have passed.

Comment: Thank you. The second approach is not considered since my memory and CPU are increasing rapidly