# I need to input some error handling into my program

Tags: python

I need to input some error handling into my program. My program takes a line of text from the user but this text should only contain letters and spaces. I have tried to input some error handling but I want to improve it. When the user enters something other than a letter or space I print an error message but the code underneath is still executed. When the user enters something that is not a letter or space I want the error message to be printed and the program to terminate.

```
print ""

# To God be the Glory

text = raw_input("Please enter a line of text: ")
text_lower = text.lower()
```

I want my error handling to be inputted around here such that if the user enters something that is not a letter or space the program will print the error message and the user will not be asked for a key.

```
print ""
key = int(input("Please enter a key: "))


def ascii_func (text) :
```

This is the error handling method I attempted it recognises if there is incorrect input but still executes the code underneath it.

```
    for charc in text_lower:
        if charc not in ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",\
    "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "]:
        print "Error input is not correct"
        break

    result = ''

    print ""

    for charc in text:


        if charc != " " :
            charc = ord(charc)
            charc = (charc - 97) + key
            charc = (charc % 26)
            charc = charc + 97
            charc = chr(charc)

        result += charc

    print result

ascii_func(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` only exits the for loop. Not the program or function. You could either use `return` to exit the function, or, if you'd rather halt the script entirely, you could use one of the options [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programatically-stop-execution-of-python-script).

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simply way to do this is as below.

```
fail = False
for charc in text_lower:
    if charc not in acceptable list:
        fail = True
        print "bad input"
        break

if not fail:
    #rest of your code goes here
```

Much nicer ways exist.  For example, you should read up on `try... except`.

For your purposes, probably the cleaner way is

```
import sys
for charc in text_lower:
    if charc not in acceptable list:
        sys.exit("bad input")
#rest of your code.
```