# How to allow a user to quit a program

Tags: python, exit

I am making a text adventure game and I am trying to allow the user to quit the game using q. I don't know what to input, here's my code.

```
print ("Welcome to Camel!")
print ("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi deset.")
print ("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down! Survive your desert trek and out run the natives.")

print ("Welcome to Camel!")
print ("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi deset.")
print ("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down! Survive your desert trek and out run the natives.")

done = False
while done == False:
    print("Print the letter only.")
    print("A. Drink from your canteen.")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed.")
    print("C. Ahead full speed.")
    print("D. Stop for the night.")
    print("E. Status check.")
    print("Q. Quit.")

    first_question = input("What do you want to do? ")

    if first_question.lower() == "q":
        done = True

    if done == True:
        quit
```

The lines are all indented properly in the code (the website makes it weird when copy pasting). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I edited your code into a code block.  In the future, you can highlight the section of code and click the button with the curly brackets `{}` to indent it for you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programatically-stop-execution-of-python-script

Comment: what is `quit` ? maybe you mean `break` or `quit()` - with `()`.  But remove `if done==True:quit` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: You could use either `if done: break` _or_ `if done: sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is nearly fine as is, and in fact it runs just fine in python3. The problem is that in python2, [input](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) will actually *evaluate* your input. In order to support python2, use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Answer (score -1):

```
print ("Welcome to Camel!")
print ("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi deset.")

print ("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down! Survive your desert trek and out run the natives.")

done = False

while done == False:

    print("Print the letter only.")

    print("A. Drink from your canteen.")

    print("B. Ahead moderate speed.")

    print("C. Ahead full speed.")

    print("D. Stop for the night.")

    print("E. Status check.")

    print("Q. Quit.")

    first_question = input("What do you want to do? ")

    if first_question.lower() == "q":

        done = True

        if done == True:

            break
```

Now, when you input 'Q' or 'q' program will quit.
It's about tabulation. Is that what you asked?

Comment: [quit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit) is a built-in method to quit

Comment: As far as I know, we use `break` to break loop, witch I can't really see here. So `quit` will do and it works.

Comment: @leaf I see. So when we use while/if `break` would be correct way to stop. But quit will also work here?

Comment: @IgorStepanov Yes. It does. But as I said in my previous comment, `quit` should no be used in actual programs, [per the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit).

Comment: @leaf Ok, I'll keep that in mind next time. I'm also learning, so don't judge me strictly

Comment: @IgorStepanov I'm not judging, and I apologize if I cam across that way. Happy coding!