# Stopping the execution of Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, turtle-graphics

I have written this question after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programmatically-stop-execution-of-python-script/543375) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script).
I would like to stop the execution of a Python script when a button is pressed. Here the code:

```
import turtle
from sys import exit

def stop_program():
    print("exit function")
    exit(0) #raise SystemExit(0) gives the same result
    print("after the exit function")

# Create keyboard binding
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(stop_program, "q")

# Main function
while True:
    # Code: everything you want
```

If I press the button "q" (even muliple time) the output is:

```
exit function
exit function
exit function
exit function
exit function
exit function
exit function
...
```

i.e. one line every time I press.
This means that the `exit` works for the function and not for the whole program. Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried `turtle.bye` instead of your `stop_program` function? https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.bye

Comment: trying now, however, what I wrote should work. The question is: why it exit from the function and not from the script execution? it is not a "return"

Comment: @Andrew: it exists but with some errors (it seems because of it is executing something else in the middle)

Comment: Can I see what you have under `while True:`? Do you happen to do `except:\n` anywhere?

Comment: after the `while True:` there are other functions defined by me. For simplicity assume that they are just `print()` (I have tried and it does not exit either). However, what do you mean with `except:\n`?

Comment: I was thinking if there were a bare `except:` (as opposed to `except Exception`) that would explain why you're not exiting all the way. This is really weird.

Comment: I have found why this happens: "Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.". I am investigating to find a "clean" solution (details from the sys module documentation)

Comment: I am realizing that it IS the main thread (but not the main function). So, probably, the reason is not the one I was pointing out in the previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the while loop, use turtle.mainloop()

```
import turtle
from sys import exit

def stop_program():
    print("exit function")
    exit(0) #raise SystemExit(0) gives the same result
    print("after the exit function")

# Create keyboard binding
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(stop_program, "q")


turtle.mainloop()
```

That seems to work fine for me, give it a try.

Comment: where is the definition of turtle.mainloop()? where I can insert my instruction? I will try to find more info surfing on google

Comment: it is built into turtle, https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop

Answer (score -1):

Try to use: sys.exit(), see if that works. Below code worked for me.

```
import turtle
import sys

def stop_program():
 print("exit function")
 sys.exit() #raise SystemExit(0) gives the same result
 print("after the exit function")


 # Create keyboard binding
 turtle.listen()
 turtle.onkey(stop_program, "q")
 turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: of course no: from sys import exit allow to write just exit instead of sys.exit(). It is the same, isn't it?

Comment: import sys and then use sys.exit(). It woks for me fine. Used mikeg's code above, but adapted it a bit with my suggestion.

Comment: did you try the code that I wrote in the question? and it works? really?

Comment: It does not work. Try the code in the question please

Comment: I edited my solution to show you what worked for me. Have a look and let me know.