# How to end module definition?

Tags: python

A common pattern I do on functions is, tip before answering the question, adding an "`else`" defeats the purpose of reducing nesting:

```py
def fun(param):
    if param is None:
        return

    return do_something_with_param(param)
```

This allows me to reduce nesting by exiting out of the function returning `None`... Now on a module definition how to "`return`" in the module earlier?

Here's an example loosely based on what I'm trying to accomplish:

settings.py:

```py
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

PROJECT_NAME = "Default Project Name"

ENV = os.getenv("ENV")

HOST = os.getenv("HOST")
PORT = os.getenv("PORT")

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")

if not DATABASE_URL:
    raise Exception("Figure out how to exit from the module earlier...")

DATABASE_URL += "?sslmode=disable"
```

As you can see if the `DATABASE_URL` is not provided (or any env variable) I would like to get out of the module and not run the rest of the code, without an `else` condition.

The module itself should be able to be imported, without the code that's at the end if the `DATABASE_URL` is not found.

Comment: by module you mean script? are you running this as a standalone script? Normally you can't control module definition, that is done in the C layer.

Comment: Raise ImportError if the module can't be successfully imported.

Comment: Put all of your module-level code inside a function, then call that function?  You can then use your `return` trick as normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically stop execution of python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programmatically-stop-execution-of-python-script)

Comment: you can use `quit()`

Comment: Not script! The module needs to be imported and work but not run  that that final line!

Comment: Would `quit()` exit my program? I only need to exit the module but be able to import it still.